ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' when import google.generativeai
When i import google.generativeai, i ran into this error about grpcio, i reinstall or upgrade both not work, seem like it is a version error.
(venv) dis@master3:~$ spark-submit /home/dis/rag-chatbot/rag-chatbot-uet/chatbot/spark_kafka.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/rag-chatbot-uet/chatbot/spark_kafka.py", line 6, in 
import google.generativeai as gen_ai
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/generativeai/init.py", line 45, in 
from google.generativeai import types
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/init.py", line 17, in 
from google.generativeai.types.discuss_types import *
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/discuss_types.py", line 22, in 
import google.ai.generativelanguage as glm
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage/init.py", line 21, in 
from google.ai.generativelanguage_v1beta.services.discuss_service.async_client import (
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/init.py", line 21, in 
from .services.discuss_service import DiscussServiceAsyncClient, DiscussServiceClient
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/discuss_service/init.py", line 16, in 
from .async_client import DiscussServiceAsyncClient
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/discuss_service/async_client.py", line 32, in 
from google.api_core import gapic_v1
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/init.py", line 16, in 
from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in 
import grpc
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/init.py", line 22, in 
from grpc import _compression
File "/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 20, in 
from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/home/dis/rag-chatbot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/init.py)
When i import google.generativeai, i ran into this error about grpcio, i reinstall or upgrade both not work, seem like it is a version error.
